# How do I create an hstore from a table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a query which returns a table of keys and values, thus:

```
 key |       value        
-----+------------------
   a | 3.73333333333333
   b | 2.3
   c | 2.76666666666667
```

I'd like to convert it into an hstore:

```
       hstore         
-----------------------
 'a' => '3.73333333333333', 'b' => '2.3', 'c' => '2.76666666666667'
```

There are hstore-producing functions that take text, a pair of texts, or even a pair of arrays, but none that take a table in this fashion.

How is this done?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested, but would this work?

```
SELECT hstore(array_agg(key ORDER BY key), array_agg(value ORDER BY key))
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work the first time I tried it because value was the result of an aggregate function (avg), and apparently nested aggregates aren't allowed, but making the original query into an aliased sub-query corrected it.